# Trouble with admob

Tags: android, admob

I can't use AdMob, I create the account, the banner unit, and then the page say: "Make the download to SDK ads..." (some like that) but the link leads to a page that has no the download link https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/download?hl=pt-BR

So where in the earth I can find the `google-services.json` file to my ads.

Is this file that I have to find?
In other older tutorials, just add the play-services was enough, but now says to download the SDK. Which SDK? What I have to do?

Thanks.

**EDITED**

Now the project compile, but the ad is not showed.

STEPS

- `google-services.json` added to app root
- AndroidManifest.xml permissions

  `android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      and android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"`

  added, and so added

  `meta-data
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
              android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"`

  and

  `activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"`
- `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`' added to gradle (project)
- `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'` and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` added to gradle (app)
- in layout

  `<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
          android:id="@+id/adView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          ads:adSize="BANNER"
          ads:adUnitId="@string/my_banner_id">
      </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>`

  - and finally in activity

  `MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
          AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
          mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);`

**Note** - this id in initialize method have to be always that? (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713)

Is missing something?

Comment: Are u using Android studio..?

Comment: @Rubin Nellikunnathu Yes. I know it have a way to create the activity to ads when you are creating the project. But mine already is done.

Comment: Why someone downgrade this question?

Answer (score 0):

from https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

try adding the following to your gradle file

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:xx.x.x'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    } 



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> If the two lines in bold above are not already in your app-level build.gradle, add them. Place the compile statement inside the dependencies section and the apply plugin statement at the bottom.

Comment: I did this. But always return a error (File missing...), and I don't  know if this is because the com.google.firebase:firebase-ads... or plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'. But I can't compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android studio , then goto Tools > Firebase . the firebase helper will do the rest whatever you want. just link your android studio to your firebase account , thats all needed.
[image]

next step firebase assistant plugin will ask which feature u need to add, select admob.
[image]

then it will show the rest of instruction and Run ur app
[image]

U r finished now withh everything u needed .

Comment: it will auto import the google-services.json file to your app module

Comment: Hey, really thanks. I did all this steps, the project was compiled normally, however the ad was not showed. I edited the question, and posted all steps that I did, if you can take a look, I'll be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use Firebase Ads SDK, so you need to add a `google-services.json` to make it works. You can get your `google-services.json` from [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

Below the step quoting from [Add Firebase to Your Android Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup):

> **Add Firebase to your app**
>
> To add Firebase to your app you'll need a Firebase project and a
>   Firebase configuration file for your app.
>
> 1. Create a Firebase project in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), if you don't already have one. If you already have an existing Google project
>      associated with your mobile app, click **Import Google Project**.
>      Otherwise, click **Create New Project**.
> 2. Click **Add Firebase to your Android** app and follow the setup steps. If you're importing an existing Google project, this may happen
>      automatically and you can just [download the config file](http://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592).
> 3. When prompted, enter your app's package name. It's important to enter the package name your app is using; this can only be set when
>      you add an app to your Firebase project.
> 4. At the end, you'll download a `google-services.json` file. You can [download this file](http://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) again at any time.
> 5. If you haven't done so already, copy this into your project's module folder, typically `app/`.